# gdb declares size of 0 for class field

Tags: c++, gdb

I loaded up a C++ library in gdb, started the built-in Python interpreter, and ran

```py
import gdb

t = gdb.lookup_type('Some::Type')
field = t.fields()[0]
print(field.bitpos)
print(field.bitsize)
```

The output is

```
0
0
```

What does it mean for a field to have a size of 0?

I've run `gdb.lookup_type` on the class of the field and it's not empty.  I *think* it's a virtual class because all it has is a vtable.

Comment: It's an empty class that's the first member of another class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bitsize` is only meaningful for bit fields or packed fields. For regular fields, the size is given by the type. Use

```
t.fields()[0].type.sizeof
```

to access the size.